# Annotating text in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, html, uiwebview, css

I am writing a app that has a UIWebView that displays a HTML5 page. I want to annotate some text on the web page and save it in SQLite database. The annotated text must be changed to a specific color as a visual effect.

Any suggestions that how can I select and get the text back in Objective-C?

Comment: Have you implemented this. Because I too need to highlight a text in uiwebview and save it in sqlite but even after searching a lot not able to do so. If you have found the solution then can you please share that.

Comment: Yes the functionality is implemented.... but the code is quite complex. We are parsing the complete HTML page in order to find out the text selected and then adding the `<span>` tag around it to highlight it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. Parse the HTML5 document by hand
2. Inject Javascript into the page and walk the document. See [Search and highlight text in UIWebView](http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/01/12/search-and-highlight-text-in-uiwebview/)